# How to create an user with an home directory?

Tags: linux

I want to create an user inmy ubuntu server, but this user CANNOT read outside his /home/user
how can i do?

Comment: We need more information. Why do you want to keep him in $HOME? Is this for ssh access? ftp? sftp?

Comment: yes exactly..... for ssh access

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want chrooted accounts. Here is a howto:

http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny

More information can be found in the sshd_config's man page:

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5

Answer (score 0):

You can use a popular jailing script written in python. Check it at the address: http://lshell.ghantoos.org/